# Does standby mode of the PS4 actually recharge your controller?

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, ps4

Patch 1.71 says that standby mode actually recharges controllers. But I am not seeing any difference in the battery level of my controller after leaving my console on standby for an hour or more with my controller connected... Is this just a case of Sony's wonderful QA? Or is there some other setting that needs to be enabled.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the main menu bar go to:

-> Settings
-> Power Save Settings
-> Set Functions Available in Standby Mode
-> Check the checkbox for Supply Power from USB Ports

Your controllers should now charge in Standby mode.

Comment: Yep that's it. Sony hasn't broken it, but they should fire their UX designer...thnx